# "Den Apfel essen, das wollte er": What is this construction called?

Tags: clauses

I believe to have heard a construction like the following:

> "Den Apfel (zu) essen, das wollte er."
> "Die Milch von Müller, die ist
> gut." **Not**  "Die Milch von Müller, die gut ist, .."

You can hear this in old advertisements.
Now I thought this might be either a noun phrase or Infinitivkonstruktion with a relative clause at the end. But a relative clause seems to have its verb always in last position.

Therefore I am confused. What is the name of constructing a sentence like this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<strike>The first sentence is a rarer variant of what is called a [cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence) or [Spaltsatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaltsatz).  In this case, it is the infinitive construction which is "cloven" from the rest.</strike> Nope, I misread -- the cleft sentence would be *Den Apfel essen war, was er wollte*.

The second one I'd just call topicalization -- you take a noun phrase and put it "free floating" at the start.

Note that both constructions are used to mention first a part of the sentencen that by default would come later.  The purpose of this is to change focus, givenness or newnewss of the fronted part.

Comment: Answered the question, thanks! What I was looking for was this.

Comment: I am not sure the description in Wikipedia matches the phenomenon in the question. There are no two clauses in the examples in the question, are there?

Comment: I agree; I applied the term by analogy and sloppily read the question. In something like _er suchte den Apfel", you front the argument of _suchen_ to _es war der Apfel, den er suchte_. In _er wollte den Apfel essen_, the whole infinitive construction _den Apfel essen_ is the argument of the predicate, and so you have the parallel movement _es war den Apfel essen, das er wollte_. But that's not what has been asked...

Comment: @OranMatheus I realized I'm wrong about the first sentence.

Comment: @phipsgabler Oh no! I skimmed through Wikipedia and noticed that Relativsatz was a requirement, but your mentioning of "Rare case of" made me think it's permittable / I didn't think enough. So you're saying both is an example of fronting/topicalization?

Comment: Probably, yes. I thought is rare because it fronts the infinitive clause, but it is actually a wholly different construction.

Comment: I appreciate a lot that you updated your answer. Too often, people react in a defensive way when their answers get challenged. Good to see that the community here can do better!

Answer (score 6):

This is not a relative pronoun. You correctly identified that the verb order is not the one that would be found in a relative clause.

The part before the comma is in one case the subject of the sentence ("Wer  ist gut?" - *Die Milch von Müller*), in the other case the object of the verb ("Was wollte er?" - *Den Apfel essen*). In your examples, it is once a noun phrase (*Die Milch von Müller*) and once a verbal phrase (*Den Apfel essen*), which you correctly specified as "Infinitivkonstruktion".

The pronouns are subject or object pronouns respectively. The pronoun can be removed, and the sentence still makes sense:

> Den Apfel essen wollte er.
> Die Milch von Müller ist gut.

You could remove the reference from the sentence, and keep the pronoun instead:

> Das wollte er.
> Die ist gut.

This demonstrates the relation between the pronoun and its reference. You could consider them *demonstrative pronouns*:

> Demonstratives are often used in spatial deixis (...), but also in intra-discourse reference (including abstract concepts) or anaphora
> It might also help to translate the sentences and mark the pronoun.

(From ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative))

> Eating the apple, he wanted *that*.
> The milk of Müller, *it* is good.

Notice that the first translation is not idiomatic in English. The translation just intends to make the grammatical structure in German more lucid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this surely has to have a name, doesn't it? It has a special sound to it. There must be a term for encapsulating the subject/object like this?

Comment: @OranMatheus Your idea that they are demonstrative pronouns is correct. I added this to my answer. Sorry for not being that specific in the first place, and thank you for your comment!

Comment: Maybe there is a particular term for that figure of speech. If it exists, I don't know it. Feel free to downvote the answer if it is just missing the point of your question :)

Comment: Ok, I will let you know if I find a term for it.

Comment: Das war bezogen auf diese deine Aussage "You could also remove the reference from the sentence, and keep the pronoun instead" Den entsprechenden Teil wird man aber nicht einfach aus dem Fragetext löschen können, nämlich "Den Apfel (zu) essen". Wenn das fehlt, dann ist die Frage doch nicht mehr nachvollziehbar.

Comment: @vectory Das habe ich geschrieben, damit man nachvollziehen kann, auf welchen Referenten sich das Pronomen bezieht. Das ist als eine Art "Ersatzprobe" zu verstehen. Ich wollte damit nicht die Frage ersetzen, sondern den Beispielsatz "herunterbrechen". Falls du einen Vorschlag hast, wie ich die Antwort klarer machen kann, freue ich mich darüber.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know whether this type of constructing sentences has a special name.

Sentences as your examples can always be rephrased in a simpler (and more standard) form:

- Den Apfel essen, das wollte er. → Er wollte den Apfel essen.
- Die Milch von Müller, die ist gut. → Die Milch von Müller ist gut.

Both variants convey the same message, but the "non-standard" variant puts a special emphasis on the part before the comma. It is a stylistic device which wants to focus the addressee's attention on the beginning of the sentence. I think it is mainly used in oral speech. The comma is expressed in form of a little pause in speech.

Instead of the comma one can also use a dash:

- Den Apfel essen - das wollte er.
- Die Milch von Müller - die ist gut.

You say that one can hear such sentences in old advertisements, but it is certainly not limited to that. For example, parents sometimes criticize their children by statements like this:

- Den ganzen Tag im Internet surfen, das kannst Du. Aber eine halbe Stunde Hausaufgaben machen, das kannst Du nicht.